# Fire an event off of every single keyboard key in jQuery

Tags: jquery, keypress

Is this possible?

Are all keys accessible to trigger some code from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch keystrokes anywhere on your page by attaching the event handling to the `document`, but it will prove more problematic to actually catch all types of keys. You should be able to catch everything that produces input, cursor movement and so on, but catching keys like Shift will be problematic.

QuirksMode has a [compatibility chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just use $(document):

```
$(document).keypress(function(){
    alert("keypress");
});
```

Comment: `document` sounds much better